# Remapping shortcut to discard auto-complete suggestion box

Tags: autocompletion

When vim suggests completions, I can discard them without accepting with `Ctrl+y`

I would like to remap that shortcut to `Escape` while keeping the usual behavior of `Escape` (exit insert mode) when no suggestion box is visible.

The answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50033076/13801624 lead me to try `inoremap <expr> <Esc> pumvisible() ? "<C-y>" : "<Esc>"` however this just makes `Escape` do nothing when a suggestion box is visible.

Comment: I think you want to use `C-E` to end completion (see here: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/insert.txt#L1312-L1313)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt That is true once you have selected one of the suggestions, but even then, it reverts but doesn't close the suggestion box. In my case I use `Tab` to scroll through the suggestions, therefore `C-y` allows me to close that box and be able to use `Tab` to insert a tab. 
The interesting part is that `C-y` does what I want, but I am unable to remap `Esc` to replicate that sequence

Comment: I don't see that. Please give complete reproduction steps

Comment: Don’t map escape. It’s going to cause all kinds of trouble.

Comment: Got it - I will find another way then.